# What's "Local.testsettings" and "TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings" files that Visual Studio create when init a new test project?

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

When create a new test project using visual studio these 2 files are created, what's the purpose of these files? If to run the tests using Visual Studio, these files apparently is not needed.

Answer (score 6):

Local.testsetting mainly used to define your test attributes. Lets assume you have set of test cases that you want to execute using a remote controller machine that you can configure in 'Host' section in this setting file. Also there are multiple other test attributes like 'TestTimeout: to set specific timeout for all your test cases, 'Setup & Cleanup Script': if you wish to run some script before running any test and after all your test cases executes. You can take this file as a Global setting file for your all test cases within this test project.

There will be another file with extension .VSMDI. This file contains list of test cases within this test project. And you can group test cases using this. For example, lets assume you have set of test cases that you want to integrate in your automatic build system and you have some other test cases (Like something opening a browser and check for some element) that you don't want to integrate with your build system. So can do all this grouping using this .vsmdi.

-Thx

Comment: Why do I need to maintain two separate lists of test cases? Why do we need the VSMDI file when the list of tests can be inferred within the project itself?

Comment: @Nuzzolilo I know this is an old question now but at my company we parse trx files for failed tests then generate vsmdi files to run the failures again. It is worth noting that in vs2015 mstest.exe has been superseded by vstest.console.exe and it doesn't support vsmdi files.